# Generating hard copy mail merge letters in Civicrm

Tags: mailing

I want to do a mail merge and post out a letter to members of a Civigroup. You can do this by generating a message template. When you insert a letterhead image into the template, the image resolution on the printed copy is poor. Is there a way to improve the resolution so that it looks professional. I presume this would be the same with invoices etc.

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/postal-mail-communications/

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, there is a new extension called CiviOffice. It is still under development but provides many features already and should be able to solve the image problem described in your question.
Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/civioffice/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If the printed version looks poor it is probably due to the quality of the image you used in the editor. You could simply upload one with better quality / resolution.

In general you may have to fiddle a bit to get your html templates work well. I would advise to use an external editor and backup your templates once they work.

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I appreciate your help. I will use a higher resolution image. When you say use an external editor, what do you mean? Would that be something like Photoshop or perhaps even Dreamweaver to edit html.

Comment: Fabian, I tried it with a high-res logo. It still looks pretty ordinary. I might just stick with a conventional mail merge in Word.

Comment: We are also working on a new extension that integrates an online office tool with CiviCRM. It is stil in development but once we have something to show for, I will post it here: https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.onlyoffice

Comment: Thank you Fabian